# Can't connect oracle Database using c#

Tags: c#, .net, odp.net

I Installed odp.net managed driver and i can make ez connections.

However i can't connect using Oracle Client's tnsnames.ora file.

There is a regedit registry which shows oracle homes correctly and i can connect databases via sqldeveloper using that tnsnames.

I am using tns aliases like below for your information.

```
 oradb = "Data Source= testtns; User Id = test; Password=test";
```

What do i miss? How can i connect using tnsnames via odp.net winform application?

Comment: which exception do you get? could it be related to the spaces in the connection string? https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-data-provider-for-net-odp-net/

Comment: @dlatikay no its not. It just doesn't read the tnsnames.